# Java Control Panel - Update tab keeps loading

Tags: java, version

I am trying to see if there are updates available for java, but the update tab keeps loading endlessly. My macOs is `macOS Monterey`. Below is how it's looking while it loads:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I went to

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-mac

and selected jdk-8u341-macosx-x64.dmg to download. Here's the link:

https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u341-b10/424b9da4b48848379167015dcc250d8d/jdk-8u341-macosx-x64.dmg

Installed this and that problem went away.
Hope this helps.